# Django DRF change serializer data with CreateListModelMixin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have this class view, but I am unable to modify the serializer data to insert more data (which is needed and needs to be populated automatically). 
Because I am creating many instances at once, the serializer is based on kwargs['many'] = True.

Any idea on how I can add another field to each serializer data?

Thanks,

:

```
class ReservedServiceView(CreateListModelMixin, ModelViewSet):
queryset = ReservedService.objects.all()
serializer_class = ReservedServiceSerializer
authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    # Create an event that is a Reflection of the Reserved Service
    serializer_data = self.request.data

    for reserved_service in serializer_data:
        print("--------",reserved_service, flush=True)

        service_id = reserved_service['original_service']

        original_service = Service.objects.get(pk=service_id)

        calendar_event = CalendarEvent()
        calendar_event.name = original_service.name
        calendar_event.description = original_service.description
        calendar_event.date = reserved_service['date']
        calendar_event.type_id = 1
        calendar_event.start_time = reserved_service['start_time']
        calendar_event.end_time = reserved_service['end_time']
        calendar_event.location_id = original_service.location.id
        calendar_event.save()

        reserved_service['associated_event'] = calendar_event.id

    print("**********1", serializer_data)
    print("**********2", self.request.data)
    serializer.save()
```

Based in:

```
class CreateListModelMixin(object):
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """ if an array is passed, set serializer to many """
    if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
        kwargs['many'] = True
    return super(CreateListModelMixin, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: And I know that if I use:

serializer.save(associated_event_id=1)

for instance, it's going to work, but I need to save different data for each serialized object. Not just the same for every one. Thanks.

Comment: you mean each `reserved_service ` in loop, you want get different `serializer` class with each condition and save it ?

Comment: Yes. I ended up overriding create in the serializer, but I wanted to do it in the view. I want to inject in each serializer data, an extra field. I did it, but when django serializes the data it doesn’f fill that new field (associated_event)

Comment: One bug I see in the code is that you are using `self.request.data` to get the serializer data which will give you the raw data which came in the request and not the validated_data which you get after calling `serializer.is_valid()` method. So, instead of `serailizer_data=self.request.data` you should use `serializer.validated_data`

Answer (score 4):

I am not able to properly get your question, but if your question is that you are not getting the extra fields which you added to the serializer in the response of the view, then here is the answer for it.

The response of this view is returned by create method of `CreateModelMixin` which passes `serializer.data` to the `data` param of `Response`. You cannot update `serializer.data` because it is an immutable object. So, to solve this you will have to override the `create` method as follows:

```
class ReservedServiceView(CreateListModelMixin, ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ReservedService.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReservedServiceSerializer
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        my_data = {}.update(serializer.validated_data)
        # Now you can work over the my_data and add extra fields to it and save it 
        # and instead of passing serializer.data we pass my_data to Response class
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(my_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try this.

However, I already did it in the serializer. How would you decide if it's better to implement this in the view or in the serializer itself? What rule do you follow? Thanks.

Comment: I prefer to do it in view.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. 